# Why does a class body affect implicit resolution?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've stumbled upon this issue by accident when I was experimenting with abstract classes. The following code:

```
import shapeless._
class A 
  [tuple <: Product, hlist <: HList]
  (tuple: tuple)
  (implicit tupleGeneric: Generic.Aux[tuple, hlist]) 
{
  private val hlist = tupleGeneric.to(tuple)
  println(hlist)
}
new A((1, 'b')) {}
```

fails to compile with the following message:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tupleGeneric: shapeless.Generic.Aux[(Int, Char),shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Char,shapeless.HNil]]]
new A((1, 'b')) {}
    ^
```

However, if I simply remove the `{}` part from `new A((1, 'b')) {}`, it finds that implicit with no problem.

Is this a Scala bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it is a recognized bug.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8104

Comment: Good one. I was about to follow up; it reminds us to ask which version of shapeless.

Comment: 2.0.0-M1, Scala 2.10.2 and 2.10.3